# Errors with CountVectorizer: No such file or directory

Tags: python, dataframe, scikit-learn

I am trying to use `CountVectorizer` on a document but I keep running into a

> **No such file or directory: 'id'** error.

My code:

```
##%%time
## Creating a 2-level index for goog_s and amaz_s
goog_s['dataset_name'] = 'goog_s'
amaz_s['dataset_name'] = 'amaz_s'
amaz_s.rename(columns = {'title':'name'}, inplace = True)

## Creating a new Dataframe containing both goog_s and amaz_s 
df_s = pd.concat([goog_s, amaz_s], axis = 0, join = 'outer', keys = ['goog_s', 'amaz_s'])

## Creating column info
df_s ["info"] = df_s["name"].astype(str) + " " + df_s["description"]


## Creating countVectorizer
cv = CountVectorizer(input='filename', encoding='iso-8859-1', 
                     decode_error='ignore', analyzer='word',
                    ngram_range=(1,1), stop_words='english',
                    binary=True)

cvRaw = cv.fit_transform(df_s)
```

I keep getting an error on the line `cvRaw = cv.fit_transform(df_s)` which reads `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'id'`.

My dataframe `df_s` contains a column called `id`. I don't know why I am getting this error.

Comment: You cannot pass a dataframe to countvectorizer. From the dataframe you have, specifically which columns's data you want to use?

Comment: @vb_rises I want to create a CountVectorizer with binary counts of 1-grams avoiding English stopwords, i.e., a vectorizer that represents records as a set of tokens. The columns in my dataset are: id, name, description, data_set (whether it belongs to google or amazon dataset since I have combined both of them), maufacturer, price, and info. I am not sure which particular column to pass to countVectorizer.

Comment: the input to CountVectorizer is expected as string. So, you should first select the column which has the data and then merge all the values and pass it.

Answer (score 0):

You should feed the `input` param as `'content'`, otherwise it will looking for the file with the names given by the fed list in `fit()`. In your case, it will be column names of `df_s` dataframe because if you iterate with a dataframe it will return the column names.

For more explanation refer to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html).

Also, for the `fit()`, you need to give a single iterator, which means a `pd.Series`.

I am not sure of you intent, the following would be my suggestion.

```
cvRaw = cv.fit_transform(df_s['info'])
```

Comment: Thank you! My intent is the following: I want to create a CountVectorizer with binary counts of 1-grams avoiding English stopwords, i.e., a vectorizer that represents records as a set of tokens. The columns in my dataset are: id, name, description, data_set (whether it belongs to google or amazon dataset since I have combined both of them), maufacturer, price, and info. I am not sure which particular column to pass to countVectorizer.